# Having An Issue With Randomly Generated Numbers - Java

Tags: java, oop

I am working on this project from the Java Programming book by Joyce Farrell, and I am having an issue with the Randomly Generated number and the user's guesses not being checked correctly. For example the user has 3 guesses, lets say their first guess it 2 and the first randomly generated number is 2 the program will print out You lose. When the guess is actually correct. Please help me. I have added the details of the program plus what I have done so far.

---

Create a lottery game application. Generate three random numbers (see Appendix D for help in
doing so), each between 0 and 9. Allow the user to guess three numbers. Compare each of the
user's guesses to the three random numbers and display a message that includes the user's 
guess, the randomly determined three-digit number, and the amount of money the user has 
won as follows.

### Matching Numbers                    Award($)

Any one matching                       10
Two matching                             100
Three matching, not in order       1000
Three matching, in exact order    1,000,000

### No match                                     0

Make certain that your application accommodates repeating digits. For example, if a user
guesses 1, 2, and 3, and the randomly generated digits are 1, 1, and 1, do not give the user
credit for three correct guesses - just one. Save the file as Lottery.

---

**My Source Code**

```
// Filename: Lottery.java
// Written by: Andy A
// Written on: 14 January 2015

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lottery {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random ranNum = new Random();

        // LIMIT Contains The Numbers From 0 - 9
        // TIMES Contains The Number of Time ranNum Should Run
        final int LIMIT = 9;
        final int TIMES = 3;

        // Users Guesses
        int usersFirstGuess;
        int usersSecondGuess;
        int usersThirdGuess;

        // Randomly Generated Numbers
        final int GenFirst = ranNum.nextInt(LIMIT);
        final int GenSecond = ranNum.nextInt(LIMIT);
        final int GenThird = ranNum.nextInt(LIMIT);

        // User is asked for 3 guesses
        System.out.println("Please enter your first guess: ");
        usersFirstGuess = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your second guess: ");
        usersSecondGuess = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your third and final guess: ");
        usersThirdGuess = userInput.nextInt();

        // Winning Amounts
        final double WinTen = 10;
        final double WinHun = 100;
        final double WinThund = 1000;
        final double WinMillion = 1000000;
        final int WinZero = 0;

        // Shows the randomly generated numbers
        for(int x = 0; x < TIMES; ++x)
            System.out.print(ranNum.nextInt(LIMIT) + " ");
        System.out.println();

        // First Generated
        if(GenFirst == usersFirstGuess ) {
            System.out.println("You have won: $" + WinTen);
        }
            else if(GenSecond == usersSecondGuess) {
                    System.out.println("You have won: $" + WinTen);
            }
            else if(GenThird == usersThirdGuess) {
                System.out.println("You have won: $" + WinTen);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you've not correctly understood the task.. Read it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```html
// Filename: Lottery.java
// Written by: Andy A
// Written on: 14 January 2015

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lottery {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random ranNum = new Random();

        // LIMIT Contains The Numbers From 0 - 9
        // TIMES Contains The Number of Time ranNum Should Run
        final int LIMIT = 9;
        final int TIMES = 3;

        // Users Guesses
        int usersFirstGuess;
        int usersSecondGuess;
        int usersThirdGuess;
        List<Integer> guesses = new ArrayList<>();

        // Randomly Generated Numbers
        final int GenFirst = ranNum.nextInt(LIMIT);
        final int GenSecond = ranNum.nextInt(LIMIT);
        final int GenThird = ranNum.nextInt(LIMIT);

        // User is asked for 3 guesses
        System.out.println("Please enter your first guess: ");
        usersFirstGuess = userInput.nextInt();
        guesses.add(usersFirstGuess);
        System.out.println("Please enter your second guess: ");
        usersSecondGuess = userInput.nextInt();
        guesses.add(usersSecondGuess);
        System.out.println("Please enter your third and final guess: ");
        usersThirdGuess = userInput.nextInt();
        guesses.add(usersThirdGuess);

        // Winning Amounts
        final double WinTen = 10;
        final double WinHun = 100;
        final double WinThund = 1000;
        final double WinMillion = 1000000;
        final int WinZero = 0;

        // Shows the randomly generated numbers
        System.out.println(GenFirst + " " + GenSecond + " " + GenThird);
        List<Integer> lottery = new ArrayList<>();
        lottery.add(GenFirst);
        lottery.add(GenSecond);
        lottery.add(GenThird);

        if (guesses.equals(lottery)) {
            System.out.println("You have won: $" + WinMillion);
        } else {
            int matchCount = 0;
            for (Integer guessValue : guesses) {
                if (lottery.contains(guessValue)) {
                    matchCount++;
                    lottery.remove(guessValue);
                }
            }

            switch (matchCount) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("You have won: $" + WinZero);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("You have won: $" + WinTen);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("You have won: $" + WinHun);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("You have won: $" + WinThund);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, The information you gave me was great, and now it works. Thank you so much everybody.

Answer (score 4):

You are printing newly generated numbers with `ranNum.nextInt(LIMIT)`, however you are comparing the user input with the numbers stored in the `GenXXX` variables.

Solution: Print the variables instead.

```
System.out.println(GenFirst + " " + GenSecond + " " + GenThird);
```

If you still want to use a loop for printing you can store the numbers in an array.

```
// generate
final int[] generated = new int[TIMES];
for (int x = 0; x < TIMES; x++)
    generated[x] = ranNum.nextInt(LIMIT);

// print
for (int x = 0; x < TIMES; x++)
    System.out.print(generated[x] + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem of the randomly generated numbers, but if your way of showing them to the user.

Before your `if / else if` statements, in the for-loop you are generating **new** random numbers. That means, the number compared to the users input (`genFirst`) can be *3*, but the number shown to the user in the for loop is a new random number, for example *2*.

To fix this problem, you should display the generated numbers like that:

```
for (int ranInt : new int[] { GenFirst, GenSecond, GenThird}) {
    System.out.println(ranInt);
}
```

This piece of code creates an array of the generated numbers and loops through them printing them. Obviously, you can also `print GenFirst`, then `print GenSecond` and then `print GenThird`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly,
why are you printing

```
System.out.print(ranNum.nextInt(LIMIT) + " ");
```

when you should be just printing

```
System.out.print(GenThird + " ");
System.out.print(GenSecond + " ");
System.out.print(GenFirst + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Qellonumrat {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand=new Random();
        int random_integer=(int) rand.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("Guess the number: ");
        int number=sc.nextInt();
        while(true){
            if(number == random_integer){
                random_integer++;
                System.out.println("Congrats you won!!!");
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Try again");
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```